# 2 Filter switch cases who can both filter at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a filter function on my application that 1 made with 2 switch cases.
I check the filter function by 2 hidden elements in each data div.
Now i need these 2 filters to be able to work together.
For example: if i selected critical and NETXMS it would only show the data with NETXMS and critical, and if they are then they need to be showed.

I dont really know how to approach this problem and a step in the right direction would be awesome.

```js
$("#select").change(function() {
                var selectedValue = document.getElementById("select").value;
                switch (selectedValue) {

                    case 'critical':
                        $(".severityNummer").parent().show();
                        $(".severityNummer:contains('3'), .severityNummer:contains('2'), " + ".severityNummer:contains('1'), .severityNummer:contains('0')").parent().hide();            
                        break;

                    case 'major':
                        $(".severityNummer").parent().show();
                        $(".severityNummer:contains('4'), .severityNummer:contains('2'), " + ".severityNummer:contains('1'), .severityNummer:contains('0')").parent().hide();
                        break;

                    case 'minor':
                        $(".severityNummer").parent().show();
                        $(".severityNummer:contains('4'), .severityNummer:contains('3'), " + ".severityNummer:contains('1'), .severityNummer:contains('0')").parent().hide();
                        break;
                    case 'warning':
                        $(".severityNummer").parent().show();
                        $(".severityNummer:contains('4'), .severityNummer:contains('3'), " + ".severityNummer:contains('2'), .severityNummer:contains('0')").parent().hide();

                        break;

                        // Als default worden alle alarmen weergegeven
                    default:
                        $(".severityNummer").parent().show();

                        break;
                } // Einde switch cases
            }
                    
            ); // Einde $("#select").change functie
            $("#origin_select").change(function() {
                // Haalt id op voor de filterknop
                var selectedValueOrigin = document.getElementById("origin_select").value;
                switch (selectedValueOrigin) {

                    case 'NETXMS':
                        $(".originValue").parent().show();
                        $(".originValue:contains('800XA')").parent().hide();

                        break;

                    case '800XA':
                       $(".originValue").parent().show();
                        $(".originValue:contains('NETXMS')").parent().hide();

                        break;
                        
                        // Als default worden alle alarmen weergegeven
                    default:
                        $(".originValue").parent().show();
 
                        break;
                } // Einde switch cases
            }
                    
            );
```

```css
.Alarm{
    border: black solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filter-body">
<p>Status
<select name="statussen" id="select">
<option value="all" class="option"> All </option>
<option value="critical" class="option"> Critical </option>
<option value="major" class="option"> Major </option>
<option value="minor" class="option"> Minor </option>
<option value="warning" class="option"> Warning </option>
 </select>
 </p>
<p>Origin
<select name="origin" id="origin_select">
 <option value="all" class="option"> All </option>
 <option value="NETXMS" class="option"> NETXMS </option>
<option value="800XA" class="option"> 800XA </option>
</select>
 </div>
 
 
 <div class="Alarm">
 <div class="Content">Content</div>
 <div class="hidden severityNummer">1</div>
 <div class="hidden originValue">800XA</div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="Alarm">
 <div class="Content">Content</div>
 <div class="hidden severityNummer">2</div>
 <div class="hidden originValue">NETXMS</div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="Alarm">
 <div class="Content">Content</div>
 <div class="hidden severityNummer">3</div>
 <div class="hidden originValue">800XA</div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="Alarm">
 <div class="Content">Content</div>
 <div class="hidden severityNummer">4</div>
 <div class="hidden originValue">NETXMS</div>
 </div>
```

Edit: added a code snippet with a not working version.

Comment: I'm sure this code can be improved, but it's hard to determine exactly how without seeing a working example of it. As such, could you please add the relevant HTML and CSS to the question in a snippet.

Comment: Its quite a big project soo i need too edit it a bit so its only for this part of the code, give me a moment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more functional approach to your problem. Note the addition of data attributes

```js
var map = {
  'all': 0,
  'critical': 1,
  'major': 2,
  'minor':3,
  'warning': 4
}

var level = "0";
var origin = "all";


function filterAlarms() {
  let $alarms = $(".Alarm") 
  
  $alarms.each((i,el) => $(el).hide())
  
  $alarms = $alarms.filter( (i, el) => map[level] == 0 || el.dataset.severity == map[level])

  $alarms = $alarms.filter( (i, el) => origin == "all" || el.dataset.origin == origin)
  
  $alarms.each((i,el) => $(el).show())
  
}

$("#select").change(function(e) {
  level = e.target.value;
  filterAlarms();

}); 

$("#origin_select").change(function(e) {
  origin = e.target.value;
  filterAlarms();            
});
```

```css
.Alarm{
    border: black solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filter-body">
<p>Status
<select name="statussen" id="select">
<option value="all" class="option"> All </option>
<option value="critical" class="option"> Critical </option>
<option value="major" class="option"> Major </option>
<option value="minor" class="option"> Minor </option>
<option value="warning" class="option"> Warning </option>
 </select>
 </p>
<p>Origin
<select name="origin" id="origin_select">
 <option value="all" class="option"> All </option>
 <option value="NETXMS" class="option"> NETXMS </option>
<option value="800XA" class="option"> 800XA </option>
</select>
 </div>
 
 
 <div class="Alarm" data-severity="1" data-origin="800XA">
 <div class="Content">Content</div>
 <div class="hidden severityNummer">1</div>
 <div class="hidden originValue">800XA</div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="Alarm" data-severity="2" data-origin="NETXMS">
 <div class="Content">Content</div>
 <div class="hidden severityNummer">2</div>
 <div class="hidden originValue">NETXMS</div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="Alarm" data-severity="3" data-origin="800XA">
 <div class="Content">Content</div>
 <div class="hidden severityNummer">3</div>
 <div class="hidden originValue">800XA</div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="Alarm" data-severity="4" data-origin="NETXMS">
 <div class="Content">Content</div>
 <div class="hidden severityNummer">4</div>
 <div class="hidden originValue">NETXMS</div>
 </div>
```